# Can't install programns or upgrade

Tags: software-uninstall, linux-headers

I have a ubuntu server 16.04, and now i can't install anything program or update.

Problem:

```
root@srvWEBSIG:/var/www/html/airc# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-130-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-130-    generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-135-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic but it is not installed
                   Recommends: thermald but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

apt-get install -f

```
    root@srvWEBSIG:/var/www/html/airc# apt-get install -f
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-130 linux-headers-4.4.0-130-generic linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-130-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 372 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/218 MB of archives.
After this operation, 326 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 427101 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic_4.4.0-135.161_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.4.0-135-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-135-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic (4.4.0-135.161) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic_4.4.0-135.161_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.4.0-135-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.4.0-135-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-135-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-135-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-135-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-135-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic_4.4.0-130.156_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.4.0-130-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-130-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic (4.4.0-130.156) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic_4.4.0-130.156_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.4.0-130-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.4.0-130-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-130-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-130-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-130-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-130-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic_4.4.0-47.68_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.4.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic (4.4.0-47.68) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic_4.4.0-47.68_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-47-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic_4.4.0-81.104_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.4.0-81-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-81-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic (4.4.0-81.104) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic_4.4.0-81.104_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.4.0-81-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.4.0-81-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-81-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-81-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-81-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-81-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic_4.4.0-98.121_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic (4.4.0-98.121) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic_4.4.0-98.121_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-98-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic_4.4.0-135.161_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic_4.4.0-130.156_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic_4.4.0-47.68_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic_4.4.0-81.104_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic_4.4.0-98.121_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

root@srvWEBSIG:/var/www/html/airc# uname -a

```
Linux srvWEBSIG 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! try to type `sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove` and run update/upgrade your kernel.

Comment: Solve -
my boot partition has full

using this guide: https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1974-how-to-fix-a-full-boot-partition-on-linux

Comment: glad to hear that.